# Pandas Time Series Plot: Secondary y-Axis Label , Set Lower Limit

Tags: python, pandas, axis-labels

I would like to have a time series plot including 2 columns - which works fine the way described below. I tried many ways to introduce a label for the secondary y axis with no success.

```
df.plot(kind='line',
    x='measurement_date',
    y=['crack_total', "crack_inv_vel"],
    secondary_y=["crack_inv_vel"],
    xlabel="date",
    ylabel="crack width [m]",
    title="crack survey")
```

Example Plot as produced with the code above:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assign the return value of `df.plot` to a variable; it will be of type `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. Then [`twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) it to get access to the secondary y-axis. Then you can adjust label etc.:

```py
ax = df.plot(kind="line",
             x="measurement_date",
             y=["crack_total", "crack_inv_vel"],
             secondary_y=["crack_inv_vel"],
             xlabel="date",
             ylabel="crack width [m]",
             title="crack survey")

ax_secondary = ax.twinx()
ax_secondary.set_ylabel("secondary y-label")
```

Comment: Many thanks! Works fine for single data frame. I face the problem now that I tried to apply it on a data frame divided into subsets - done with groupby. The initial code worked fine and produced the plots for all the subsets in one go - but no idea how to set the laben of the secondary y axis. With the proposed method I get the error message: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'twinx' - any Idea? Maybe it is easier if I use another method to generate the subsets, e.g. writing them out in single df's or arrays - not going into details here.

Comment: @PhilippeNater That is somewhat a different problem, so you might want to ask another question together with the code and error you mention.

Comment: Dear Mustafa, you are right, somewhat a different problem statement. My aim was just to work the whole thing down one by one. First step resolved.
I'll set up another question together with the code and a snippet of the .csv as well.